# How can I show an html area when a custom checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

The issue i'm having is telling when a custom checkbox has been checked? When it is checked i'd like to show the itemShipping div. As far as I can tell, the input isn't actually being checked, just the :after element on the label changes. Any help is much appreciated :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/0.3.7/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input class="styled" type="checkbox" id="itemWillShip" name="itemWillShip">
  <label for="itemWillShip">&nbsp;Will Ship</label>
</div>

<div id="itemShipping">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label for="productShippingInfo" class="required">Shipping Information</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="productShippingInfo" name="productShippingInfo"></textarea>
    <span id="error" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Add all information about your shipping details such as price, shipping method, ect.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Reference the elements
var itemShipping = $('#itemShipping');
var checkbox = $('#itemWillShip');
// A function for hiding and showing the div
function toggleItemShipping(){
 itemShipping.toggle(checkbox.prop('checked'));
}
// Event handler for clicking the checkbox
checkbox.on('change', toggleItemShipping);
// When the page loads set the correct state
toggleItemShipping();
```

Here's the full thing:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/0.3.7/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input class="styled" type="checkbox" id="itemWillShip" name="itemWillShip">
  <label for="itemWillShip">&nbsp;Will Ship</label>
</div>

<div id="itemShipping">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label for="productShippingInfo" class="required">Shipping Information</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="productShippingInfo" name="productShippingInfo"></textarea>
    <span id="error" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Add all information about your shipping details such as price, shipping method, ect.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Reference the elements
var itemShipping = $('#itemShipping');
var checkbox = $('#itemWillShip');
// A function for hiding and showing the div
function toggleItemShipping(){
 itemShipping.toggle(checkbox.prop('checked'));
}
// Event handler for clicking the checkbox
checkbox.on('change', toggleItemShipping);
// When the page loads set the correct state
toggleItemShipping();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put following in CSS

```
#itemShipping{
  display: none;
}
```

Use following jquery code for showing div in document on load

```
if($("#itemWillShip ").is(":checked") == true)
  $("#itemShipping").show();

$('#itemWillShip').click(function() {
    $("#itemShipping").toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work if the page ever loads with the checkbox already checked

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#itemShipping").hide();
    $('#itemWillShip').click(function () {
        if($('#itemWillShip').prop("checked") == true)
        {
            $("#itemShipping").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#itemShipping").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Register [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler for the checkbox. Then, (depending on whether the checkbox is `checked` or not) [`.toggle(display)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-displayjquery%20:checked) the `#itemShipping` div:

```
$('#itemWillShip').change(function(){
  $("#itemShipping").toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

The [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change) method at the end is used here to display/hide div initially. It won't *change* `checked` property, just calls event handler.

---

Demo:

```js
$('#itemWillShip').change(function () {
  $("#itemShipping").toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/0.3.7/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input class="styled" type="checkbox" id="itemWillShip" name="itemWillShip">
  <label for="itemWillShip">&nbsp;Will Ship</label>
</div>

<div id="itemShipping">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label for="productShippingInfo" class="required">Shipping Information</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="productShippingInfo" name="productShippingInfo"></textarea>
    <span id="error" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Add all information about your shipping details such as price, shipping method, ect.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```